# Are To-Do Items supposed to email the user when assigned?

Tags: workflow, email, tasks, task-list

When adding a to-do item in a Workflow, is it supposed to email the User when the item is assigned? How about adding it to the Task-List in Outlook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is specific to Issues Lists and Tasks Lists. There is a setting the List Settings -> Advanced Settings that lists if you would like to email the assigned user upon creating the item.

Picture is from 2007, but the same setting is across all versions.

[image]

To answer your question, if you have a list that doesn't derive from the parent Tasks/Issues list, you will need to either set an alert on the list, or create a simple workflow that will email the user on creation/modification.